# Why I am not getting out of loop? Even My input is correct

Tags: java, performance, while-loop, try-catch

public void getLogin()throws IOException{
int x=1;

```
    do {
        try {
            data.put(961668 , 2255);
            data.put(961768 , 2253);
            data.put(961568 , 2353);

            System.out.println("----------Welcome to the ATM Machine Project----------");
            
            System.out.println("Enter your Account number: ");
            setAccountNumber(menuOutput.nextInt());
            
            System.out.println("Enter your correct PIN number: ");
            setPinNumber(menuOutput.nextInt());
        
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("\n"+"You have Enter Incorrect value !! you have to enter only numbers: "+"\n");
            x=2;
        }
        for(Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : data.entrySet()) {
            if(entry.getKey()== getAccountNumber() && entry.getValue()== getPinNumber()) {
                getAccountType();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n"+"Wrong Account or Pin Number "+"\n");
    }while(x == 1);
}
```

Is there any reason, performance or otherwise, to prefer one over the other?
Where am I doing Mistake?  I check every thing.

Comment: Where do you set `x` to something else than `1`? That would be the only cause to break the `do` ... `while(x == 1)` loop.

Answer (score 1):

The do loop executes as long as the value of x is 1. Which in your case is not changed even when the desired result is achieved.

May be try updating the value of x to some other value except 1 in valid scenario as well.